# Outputting array with elements containing spaces

Tags: arrays, bash

I have successfully made a join function, which joins an array to a string using the delimeter:

```
function join() # Usage: string=$(join "delimeter" "${array[@]}" )
{
    local array=( "${@:2}" )
    OLD_IFS="$IFS"
    IFS="$1"
    local string="${array[*]}"
    IFS="$OLD_IFS"
    echo "$string"
}
```

I have also tried to make a split function which should do the opposite:

```
function split() # Usage: array=( $(split "delimeter" "$string") )
{
    OLD_IFS="$IFS"
    IFS="$1"
    local array=( $2 )
    IFS="$OLD_IFS"
    echo "${array[@]}"
}
```

But, when I use the split command and the result contains spaces, it will not work as expected.
Example:

```
array=( "foo" "bar" "baz" "foo bar" )
string=$(join "|" "${array[@]}")
echo $string
array=( $(split "|" "$string") )
for i in ${array[@]}
do
    echo $i
done
```

The last element "foo bar" has been split too.
I think the solution is that you have to do `array=( "$(split '|' "$string")" )`, but I do not know how to nest the quotes probably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that IFS can be a local variable in a function, so you don't have to backup and restore its value:

```
join () { local IFS="$1"; local s="${@:2}"; printf "%s" "$s"; }
```

Here's an implementation of split that requires an eval:

```
# usage: split varName separator stringToSplit
split () {
  local var="$1"
  local IFS="$2"
  set -- $3
  echo "declare -a $var=( $(printf "\"%s\" " "$@") )"
}
```

Demonstration

```
$ a=( foo bar "hello world" baz )
$ s=$(join , "${a[@]}")
$ echo $s
foo,bar,hello world,baz
$ split b , "$s"
declare -a b=( "foo" "bar" "hello world" "baz"  )
$ eval $(split b , "$s")
$ for x in "${b[@]}"; do echo "$x"; done
foo
bar
hello world
baz
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is at the end of your `split ()` function. You serialize array back to string! So it is again string separated by spaces, which does not recognize if the space was within the items or not. So, I know it is not very clean, but you'll have to return the value from `split()` function using a global variable (omit the keyword `local` in the example, and simplify the call, and and double quotes to the for command and some other cosmetic changes and it works...:

```
function split() # Usage: array=( $(split "delimeter" "$string") )
{
    OLD_IFS="$IFS"
    IFS="$1"
    array2=( $2 )
    IFS="$OLD_IFS"
}


array=( "foo" "bar" "baz" "foo bar" )
string=$(join "|" "${array[@]}")
echo $string
split "|" "$string"
for i in "${array2[@]}"
do
    echo $i
done
```

Don't know if there is cleaner way, to avoid the global variable, but I doubt.